# Python Dataframe Convert string to list type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file coming from the field. It has the data in a peculiar format. That is, a list of values in string format. I want to convert it to the list type

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['-1,0,1,2,10','1.5,2,4,5'],'y':['2.5,2.4,2.3,1.5,0.1','5,4.5,3,-0.1']})
df =
                   x                          y
0  '-1, 0, 1, 2, 10'  '2.5, 2.4, 2.3, 1.5, 0.1'
1     '1.5, 2, 4, 5'          '5, 4.5, 3, -0.1'
```

Expected answer:

```
df = 
                   x                          y
0  [-1, 0, 1, 2, 10]  [2.5, 2.4, 2.3, 1.5, 0.1]
1     [1.5, 2, 4, 5]          [5, 4.5, 3, -0.1]
```

Comment: Use `str.split`: `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(', '))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applymap` with `ast.literal_eval` would be the fastest option

```
import ast

df.applymap(ast.literal_eval)
```

Note this will produce tuples in output, although it doesn't matter but if you specifically need lists in your output then we can chain another `applymap`

```
df.applymap(ast.literal_eval).applymap(list)
```

---

```
                   x                          y
0  [-1, 0, 1, 2, 10]  [2.5, 2.4, 2.3, 1.5, 0.1]
1     [1.5, 2, 4, 5]          [5, 4.5, 3, -0.1]
```