# Python Dataframe Drop Bad lists Using Numpy logical operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame filled with lists. I want to extract min and max from each and drop the ones below a specified value. I written a function in which the first part is completed using numpy functions and later part was computed using dataframe. I want to know is this (dataframe approach) a best approach? Can I perform the second part using numpy as well? In the below example, I first drop negative values.

my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[[-1,0,1,2,10],[1.5,2,4,5]],'y':[[2.5,2.4,2.3,1.5,0.1],[5,4.5,3,-0.1]]})

def drop_bad_data(df):
  x@ymax_list,yatxmax_list = [],[]
  for row in df[['x','y']].to_numpy():
      itm = np.array([*row])
      ### Drop negative values
      itm = itm[;,(a>0).all(axis=0)]
      ### find max index
      idx = itm.argmax(1) # idx = [xmax_index,ymax_index]
      ### find x@ymax, y@xmax and append to list
      y@xmax,x@ymax = itm[[1,0],idx]
      ### append
      x@ymax_list.append(x@ymax)
      y@xmax_list.append(y@xmax)
   auxdf = pd.DataFrame({'x@ymax':x@ymax_list,'y@xmax':y@xmax_list})
   auxdf['Bad_list'] = (auxdf['x@ymax']<1)&(auxdf['y@xmax']<2)
   df = df[auxdf['Bad_list']]
     return df
```

I am guessing doing the second part (reproduced below) using numpy will reduce the processing time?

```
      ### append
      x@ymax_list.append(x@ymax)
      y@xmax_list.append(y@xmax)
   auxdf = pd.DataFrame({'x@ymax':x@ymax_list,'y@xmax':y@xmax_list})
   auxdf['Bad_list'] = (auxdf['x@ymax']<1)&(auxdf['y@xmax']<2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through rows and analyzing lists, use explode, groupby, and vectorization to test everything without iterating.  Here's one way to do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[[-1,0,1,2,10],[1.5,2,4,5]],'y':[[2.5,2.4,2.3,1.5,0.1],[5,4.5,3,-0.1]]})

for col in ['x', 'y']:
    dfe = df[[col]].explode(col).reset_index()

    dfe_min = dfe.groupby('index')[col].min().reset_index()
    dfe_max = dfe.groupby('index')[col].max().reset_index()
    dfe_min = dfe_min.rename(columns={col:col + '_min'})
    dfe_max = dfe_max.rename(columns={col:col + '_max'})
    dfe_min = dfe_min.merge(dfe_max, on='index', how='left')

    df = df.join(dfe_min)
    del df['index']
```

to get

```
                   x                          y  x_min  x_max  y_min  y_max
0  [-1, 0, 1, 2, 10]  [2.5, 2.4, 2.3, 1.5, 0.1]   -1.0     10    0.1    2.5
1     [1.5, 2, 4, 5]          [5, 4.5, 3, -0.1]    1.5      5   -0.1    5.0
```

Then filter all rows by min & max

```
# figure out what values you want to require
value_a, value_b, value_c, value_d = 0, -1, 1, 1
df = df[(df['x_min'] > value_a) & (df['y_min'] > value_b) & (df['x_max'] > value_c) & (df['y_max'] > value_d)]
```

to get

```
                x                  y  x_min  x_max  y_min  y_max
1  [1.5, 2, 4, 5]  [5, 4.5, 3, -0.1]    1.5      5   -0.1    5.0
```