# Python Dataframe Resample List Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame and I am providing a plot to explain what I am looking for. My dataframe has lists as cells.

[image]

Actual points are provided ones, resample data are the ones to be calculated.

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Xact':[[1.5,2.5,2.9,3.4,3.8,4.7,5.2,8.4,10.3]],'Yact':[[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,40,20]]})

df['Xnew'] = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
# calculate df['Ynew']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Xact':[1.5,2.5,2.9,3.4,3.8,4.7,5.2,8.4,10.3],
                   'Yact':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,40,20]})

df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Xact': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
```

You can then combine the two dataframes and interpolate. There are several interpolation methods (see. [scipy's documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)):

```
pd.concat([df, df_new]).set_index('Xact').sort_index().interpolate(method='index')
```

initial data:

[image: initial]

interpolated data (`method="linear"`):

[image: interpolated]

interpolated data (`method="index"`):

[image: interpolated (index)]