# Python Dataframe Include Common points in lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe made of lists. Two columns: x and y. I want to include common points in x and corresponding points in y.

My code:

```
df = 
                  x                        y     
0     [0, 1.1, 2, 8, 10]  [0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]  
1     [0, 1.1, 3, 4, 10]  [0, 100, 200, 300, 400]  
2     [0, 1.1, 4, 9, 10]  [0, 300, 500, 700, 900]
```

Expected answer:

```
df = 
          xcmd            y     
0     [0, 1.1, 10]  [0, 1.5, 4.5]  
1     [0, 1.1, 10]  [0, 100, 400]  
2     [0, 1.1, 10]  [0, 300, 900]
```

Comment: what makes two points common

Comment: What you mean common here ~ if more than 3 row , item should included in each ?

Comment: @ifly6 I am trying to find common floats in whole x lists and drop remaining in x and corresponding position points in y.

Comment: @BENY Yes, item that exists in all the lists in x column.

Comment: @Mainland what if there are three rows?

Comment: @ifly6 I just edited my question with three rows.

Comment: Okay, so you want common over all X sublists?

Comment: @Mainland can you provide your sample `df` with `.to_dict()`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
from collections import Counter

temp= df.apply(pd.Series.explode)

l=Counter(temp.x)

s=[x for x, count in l.items() if count==df.shape[0]]

res = temp[temp.x.isin(s)]

res = res.groupby(level=0).agg(list)

>>>print(res)   
              x              y
0  [0, 1.1, 10]  [0, 1.5, 4.5]
1  [0, 1.1, 10]  [0, 100, 400]
2  [0, 1.1, 10]  [0, 300, 900]
```

Let me know if you need some explanation about how it works.